# How to get save confirmation dialog result of outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, office-interop, office-automation

I don't know how to get result of save confirmation dialog of outlook (in C#).
This confirmation box is opened up by following:

- Open mail in outlook
- Made some changes in content
- Close the mail

[Please refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJhDc.png)

I want to get this opened save confirm box and its result.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may have to listen to events, in this case probably `OnInfoBarDismissClicked`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.infobarclickedeventargs?view=outlook-js-1.11&preserve-view=true

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Track the `MailItem.Close` / `Write` / `AfterWrite`  events - `Close` will fire immediately before the prompt is shown, `Write` fires before the message is saved, `AfterWrite` immediately afterward.

Answer (score 1):

There is no trivial way of getting such information. But you may track the sequence of events fired for the item and realize the answer following that way.

First, to handle item-level events you may develop a wrapper for an Outlook item like described in the [Implement a wrapper for inspectors and track item-level events in each inspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-implement-a-wrapper-for-inspectors-and-track-item-level-events-in-each-inspector) article.

The [MailItem.Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.close(even)) event is fired when the *inspector* associated with an item (which is an instance of the parent object) is being closed.

The [MailItem.Write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.write) event is fired  when an instance of the parent object is saved, either explicitly (for example, using the `Save` or `SaveAs` methods) or implicitly (for example, in response to a prompt when closing the item's inspector).

So, if you have got `Close` fired following by the `Write` event - that is your case!